# Trying to convert strings to symbols

Tags: ruby, arrays

This creates an infinite loop and i'm blanking as to why this happens. When I don't use the push command, the loop doesn't happen.

```
#strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
symbols = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
symbols.each do |x| 
  symbols.push(x.to_sym)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code appends items to `symbols` array (**the same array**), while iterate it; the block provides infinite items by appending to the array. (`each` use those items for iteration)

```
symbols.each do |x| symbols.push(x.to_sym) end
#^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^
```

---

Use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) instead:

```
symbols.map { |x| x.to_sym }
# => [:a, :b, :c]
symbols.map &:to_sym
# => [:a, :b, :c]
```

or use another array instead of using the same array.

```
new_symbols = []
symbols.each do |x| new_symbols.push(x.to_sym) end
new_symbols
# => [:a, :b, :c]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because, in each iteration with `#each` method you keep adding a new element to your original array `symbols`. Which causes an infinite loop. Rather do as below using [`Array#each_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index):

*code - I*

```
symbols = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
symbols.each_index do |i|
  symbols[i]=symbols[i].to_sym
end
symbols # => [:a, :b, :c]
```

But the above code will update your original array. A slight modification in your code will do work as well :

*code - II*

```
symbols = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
nw_ary = symbols.each_with_object([]) do |e,a|
  a << e.to_sym
end
nw_ary # => [:a, :b, :c]
```

But you could also use `symbols.map(&:to_sym)` inplace of *code -II* and 
`symbols.map!(&:to_sym)` inplace of *code -I*. Read [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) .